# Determining Sequence From Generating Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Consider these two functions $$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n = \frac{1-5x}{1-4x+3x^2}$$

and $$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n = \frac{3+3x}{1+x-2x^2}$$

I can see from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251063/how-can-i-determine-the-sequence-generated-by-a-generating-function) that the general strategy is to expand the polynomial, but the second method given, for a fraction, is a trick that doesn't work in this case.

How can I solve these two problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at one and the other works the same way. Since we can factorize the denominator we can write it as partial fractions.

$$F(x)=\frac{1-5x}{3x^2-4x+1}=\frac{2}{1-x}-\frac1{1-3x}=\left(2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i\right)-\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(3x)^i\right) \\ \implies F(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2-3^i)x^i$$

**Note:** Sum of geometric series $1+x+x^2+\cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}$